# Line-break in exec working or not in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to solve [SIZECON](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/sum-of-positive-integers-spoj-sizecon/22964?noredirect=1#comment47401_22964) problem in as shortest code as possible.Score is equal to size of source code of my program except symbols with ASCII code ≤ 32

```
exec'i=r();s+=i*(i>0);'*r()  # working fine
exec'i=r()\ns+=i*(i>0)\n'*r()  # working fine, but increase in 2 char
```

I was thinking that **\n** has ASCII value < 32 and so it will not be counted, but instead it is counted as 2 char.

When I just pressed enter in place of **\n**, it gives error

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I thought that it will work, but it doesn't, why?

Comment: ASCII < 32 base 10, or base 16? ;)

Answer (score 0):

`\n` is not the character 0xd, but a string literal consisting of two characters, backslash and n, that the interpreter will convert to a 0xd newline character. Since newline characters have special behaviour, this is necessary.

I'd expect those characters to be counted.